# How do you solve an equation in relation to curvature?

Tags: calculus, curvature

[Image of the the points and lines.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Oh45.png) Show that
$$  \frac{MN}{KL} = 1 + \Big( \frac{LN - KM}{KL} \Big).  $$

I am unsure how to even start this problem.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just observe that $KL+LN=KN$ and $KN-KM=MN$. Therefore $KL+LN-KM=MN$. Now divide by $KL$ throughout.